# Implicite Intent which open file manager

Tags: android, file, android-intent

my question is very simple. I want open random file manager in my activity with this method:

```
private void openFile() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("file://"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

but it doesnt works. Everytime I get this error:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9107): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent...
```

What is wrong? Is necessary write some piece of code in AndroidManifest?

Thanks for help.

Comment: your URI is incomplete. That is why android cannot find which activity to open.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED - I try this with ACTION_GET_CONTENT and intent.setType("file/*") and it works perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

You use this action to browse the files.

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   intent.setType("file/*");
   startActivity(intent);
```